# Como atribuir um valor a uma opção de um select (elemento HTML) e exibir dados associados a esse valor? ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Possuo um select que está sendo 'populado' da seguinte forma em minha aplicação ASP.NET:

```
   <select id="id_select" class="form-control">
                        @foreach (var x in listay)
                        {
                          <option  value = "@x.nome"> @x.nome </option>
                        }
   </select>
```

Dessa forma, estou conseguindo exibir os nomes que possuo na "listay".

Entretanto, minha aplicação deve exibir na tela todos os dados referentes ao nome que o usuário clicar em uma opção do select. Como, por exemplo: Ao clicar em uma opção - o nome "João", por exemplo - outros dados que estão associados ao `João` devem ser exibidos logo abaixo na tela, como sobrenome, idade, data de nascimento, etc. Eu possuo todos esses dados em minha "listay" - e consigo acessá-los usando "@x.sobrenome", "@x.idade", "@x.dataNascimento" - mas não sei como posso associar esses dados à opção que o usuário clicar no select.

Por gentileza, alguém saberia me orientar como proceder para resolver tal impasse? Desde já agradeço pela vossa atenção.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso utilizando o Javascript para pegar o momento em que o usuário muda o select. O nome desse evento é '**onchange**'.

Antes de mais nada é importante que no atributo value da tag option você coloque uma chave única, a qual o usuário pode ser identificado. Geralmente é colocado o id. Então seguindo o seu exemplo, a primeira coisa que você deveria fazer é algo parecido com isso:

```
<select id="id_select" class="form-control">
   @foreach (var x in listay)
   {
      <option value="@x.id"> @x.nome </option>
   }
</select>
```

Dessa forma, cada option terá o seu próprio valor e ficará mais fácil de você identificar quais dados você deve exibir de acordo com a opção selecionada pelo usuário.

Após isso você pode criar a função que valida qual usuário foi selecionado e adicionar o onchange direto no HTML:

```
<select id="id_select" class="form-control" onchange="BuscarDados(this);">
   //Options
</select>
```

**Função no Javascript**

```
function BuscarDados(elemento){
   
   let idSelecionado = elemento.children[elemento.selectedIndex];
   
   // Suponhamos que o id do João é igual a 3, logo... Você poderá exibir os dados do João dentro do if
   if(idSelecionado == 3){
      // Código para exibir os campos do João

   }

}
```

Comment: Olá! Obrigado pela resposta! Poderia me ajudar com uma dúvida? No que se refere ao "Código para exibir os campos do João", como eu poderia 'chamar' os dados - como x.sobrenome, x.idade, x.dataNascimento - na função Javascript, se eles estão dentro do 'foreach' que popula o select? Agradeço a atenção.

Comment: Riccarsan, tem algumas formas de fazer isso. A primeira é utilizar o controller para buscar os dados do usuário específico que você quer e depois utilizar uma ViewBag ou ViewData para passar os dados para a View. A segunda é acessar isso diretamente na lista, com linq. Você poderia criar uma variável global, dentro do @{} no início da página, algo do tipo: var dadosLista = listay.Where(x => x.id == idUsuarioQueVoceQuer); Depois é só acessar no código: @dadosLista.sobrenome e etc. Mas já adianto que o mais comum é com ViewBag. Caso tenha te ajudado, poderia marcar a pergunta como resolvida? Abç